# Adding key-value pairs of object into another object

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

is it possible to add specific key-value pairs from one object to another object WHILE initializing?

```
const a = {
    android: {
        time: null,
        diff: null
   }
};

const b = {
    out:{
       x: null,
       context:{
           state: null,
           value: null,
           "a.android key-value pairs right here: 
            time: null,
            diff: null"
       }
    }
 };
```

Comment: @Adelin That should be the best answer. **Jan**, clarify exactly what you want instead of asking if it's possible. :)

Comment: Yes, of course https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 7):

You may merge two objects like:

```
Object.assign(b.out.context, a.android)
```

```js
const a = {
    android: {
        time: null,
        diff: null
   }
};

let b = {
    out:{
       x: null,
       context:{
           state: null,
           value: null,
            time: 1,
            diff: null
       }
    }
 };
 
Object.assign(b.out.context, a.android);
console.log(b);
```

**UPD**

If you want to do it on initialization you may use **...** (spread) operator:

```js
const a = {
    android: {
        time: 1,
        diff: 2
   }
};

let b = {
    out:{
       x: null,
       context:{
           state: null,
           value: null,
           time: 3,
           diff: 4,
           ...a.android
       }
    }
 };
 

console.log(b);
```

Comment: So there isn't any cool ecmascript syntax to merge WHILE initializing?

Comment: @Jan it is here, is called SPREAD, it merges or add new properties to an object. I've updated my answer.